# как проверить значение css в if ( ) конструкции?

Tags: javascript, css

мне нужно в конструкции if() проверить значение css display когда оно равно flex, то есть когда условие if(display=Flex) то выпоняется код. Как это проверить?

```
  if(popupContainer.style.display = "flex"){
    popupContainer.addEventListener('click',function(){
    popupContainer.style.display = "none";
    });
```

есть такой пример но он не проверяет а сразу присваивает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474385/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-javascript)

Comment: Вопрос [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1484630/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-display-none-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-flex-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB) , можно было тут и спросить.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(popupContainer.style.display == "flex") {}
// или
if(popupContainer.style.display === "flex") {}
```

Comment: Ответ также должен содержать объяснение, без него (объяснения), непонятно, каким образом ответ решает задачу. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1484651/edit)»

Comment: @ΝNL993 Тут нет никакого алгоритма, простая очепятка, всё нормально :)

Comment: @EzioMercer тогда вопрос можно закрывать по причине опечатки.

Comment: @ΝNL993 За что собственно я и проголосовал :)